# Why do I get NameError: global name 'phase' is not defined

Tags: python, matplotlib, global, nameerror

I'm trying to add some interactivity to the plots, that is, a left-click should delete a data point in the plot and a right-lick should restore the deleted data points in reverse order. Here's the relevant excerpt from my Python script:

```
def plot_folded_light_curve(best_frequency, method):
    x_time = np.asarray(x_period)
    phase = (x_time * best_frequency) % 1

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
    plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.25, bottom=0.25)

    blue_scatter = plt.scatter(phase, y_m0, color="blue", picker=10)

    # delete data points in the raw light curve plot by left-clicks
    def pick_handler(event):
        global phase
        if event.mouseevent.button==1:
            ind = event.ind
            print "Deleting data point:", ind[0], np.take(phase, ind[0]), np.take(y_m0, ind[0])
            deleted_phase.append(phase[ind[0]])
            phase_index.append(ind[0])
            phase = np.delete(phase, [ind[0]])
            deleted_y_m0.append(y_brightness[ind[0]])
            y_m0_index.append(ind[0])
            del y_m0[ind[0]]
            deleted_blocks_items.append(sorted(blocks[blocks.keys()[0]].items())[ind[0]])
            del blocks[blocks.keys()[0]][sorted(block)[ind[0]]]
            blue_scatter.set_offsets(phase,y_m0)
            fig.canvas.draw()

    # restore data points in the raw light curve plot by right-clicks
    def click_handler(event):
        global phase
        if event.button == 3:
            if len(deleted_phase) > 0:
                print "Restoring data point:", phase_index[-1], deleted_phase[-1], deleted_y_m0[-1]
                phase = np.insert(phase, phase_index.pop(), deleted_phase.pop())
                y_m0.insert(y_m0_index.pop(), deleted_y_m0.pop())
                blocks[blocks.keys()[0]].update([deleted_blocks_items[-1]])
                deleted_blocks_items.pop()
                blue_scatter.set_offsets(np.c_[phase,y_m0])
                fig.canvas.draw()
            else:
                print "No deleted data points left!"

    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', pick_handler)
    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', click_handler)
```

When I run the script and when it comes to the call of function `pick_handler()` I get an error message:

```
  File "/usr/local/bin/apex_geo_lightcurve.py", line 624, in pick_handler
    print "Deleting data point:", ind[0], np.take(phase, ind[0]), np.take(y_m0, ind[0])
NameError: global name 'phase' is not defined
```

I don't understand why is it not defined? What am I doing wrong? Could someone help me there?

This runnable test script worked fine, though:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.asarray([1, 3, 5])
y = [2, 4, 6]

deleted_x = []
deleted_y = []
x_index= []
y_index= []

# delete data points in the raw light curve plot by left-clicks
def pick_handler(event):
    global x
    if event.mouseevent.button==1:
        ind = event.ind
        print ind
        print "Deleting data point:", ind[0], np.take(x, ind[0]), np.take(y, ind[0])
        deleted_x.append(x[ind[0]])
        x_index.append(ind[0])
        x = np.delete(x, [ind[0]])
        deleted_y.append(y[ind[0]])
        y_index.append(ind[0])
        del y[ind[0]]
        blue_scatter.set_offsets(np.c_[x, y])
        fig.canvas.draw()

# restore data points in the raw light curve plot by right-clicks
def click_handler(event):
    global x
    if event.button == 3:
        if len(deleted_x) > 0:
            print "Restoring data point:", x_index[-1], deleted_x[-1], deleted_y[-1]
            x = np.insert(x, x_index.pop(), deleted_x.pop())
            y.insert(y_index.pop(), deleted_y.pop())
            blue_scatter.set_offsets(np.c_[x, y])
            fig.canvas.draw()
        else:
            print "No deleted data points left!"

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
blue_scatter = plt.scatter(x, y, color="blue", picker=10)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', pick_handler)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', click_handler)
plt.show()
```

By the way, if I understand it right, I should be able to use the whole thing without globals, if I simply pass `phase` during the function call, but I dont know how to do that correctly in this case.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.
Specifically: (1) get rid of all the overhead that doesn't affect the problem; (2) trace (with `print`) where you set `phase` before you call `pick_handler`.  I strongly suspect that you do *not* reach that assignment statement first.

Comment: `phase` is simply not a global in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running Python 3?  Try using `nonlocal phase` instead of `global phase`.

The problem is that your definition of `phase` isn't "global", it's defined inside a function definition that happens to surrounds me.  `global` doesn't mean "defined somewhere outside of me".  It really means "defined in the global scope".

Alternatively, you could add `global phase` to `plot_folded_light_curve`.  This works in both Python2 and Python3.  It forces all the occurrences of phase to be global.

Comment: They are not using python 3 ...  this can be determined by the use of `print "..."` without parentheses

Comment: @Frank-Yellin Thank you! I'm using 2.7. Adding `global phase`to `plot_folded_light_curve` did the trick.

Comment: @donkopotamus: Yeah, I should have noticed that.    Sergius: Yeah, I've made this same mistake many times.